# Change iframe src with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

How can I dynamically set iframe src value? I have tried this doesn't change the src. If someone can help I would really appreciate.

HTML

```
<a href="#example" id="test">test</a>
<aside id="example" class="modal">
<div>
<iframe width="650" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/EgF81M7hMSE" height="366"      
id="iframe" frameborder="0"></iframe> <a href="#close" title="Close"></a>
</div>
</aside>
```

JS

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#test").click(function(){
$("#iframe").attr("src", "http://www.youtube.com/embed/3XviR7esUvo"); 
}); });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GPCK2/

Comment: I was just going to say the same thing. Here's a revised [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GPCK2/2/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to include JQuery in your fiddle.

Comment: @mikeykk Ah no worries. Happens to the best of us =D. Try looking at the console next time. It showed me right away `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like all you needed was the jQuery inclusion, but `$('#iframe').src = "url";` is a simpler way  of doing it.